# Where is the preferences file for the Adobe Application Manager Update Notifier menubar app?

Tags: macos, menu-bar, adobe

On my OSX 10.6 MacBook, the Adobe Application Manager menubar app always launches at login. It's supposed to have a settings button but this button does not appear since the app only shows "The update server is not responding".

I want to disable this menubar app from launching automatically at login, but since it won't let me do this in it's own settings, I was wondering if I could find the preferences file and change it manually.

Answer (score 3):

If Adobe behaved itself it'd have an option in the Login Items under Apple > System Preferences > Accounts. But it's worth keeping that in mind for other apps you may want to prevent from logging in.

As for disabling Adobe Application Manager, you actually need to create a `com.adobe.AdobeUpdater.Admin.plist` file in your user's Library Preferences folder. The easiest way to do this is using the Terminal.

Follow these steps:

1. Launch Terminal app (usually found in your Utilities folder within the Applications folder)
2. Once it opens, copy and paste the following command:

   `defaults write com.adobe.AdobeUpdater.Admin Disable.Update -bool yes`
3. Press <kbd>return</kbd>

Now the plist file should be created and Adobe Update Manager should no longer launch when you login.

Answer (score 0):

"Update server not responding" is probably because of yesterday's massive network outages. I saw the same this morning.

If 'Try Again' doesn't work, then hit Cancel, that should drop it back to normal, but the Creative Cloud menu app has an update in the pipeline, so you'll probably have to do that before you can access the regular menu structure again.

Once you have the update, then you can access the Prefs from the menu icon top right - 3 vertical dots - which will allow you to switch off the automatic launch at login. Adobe products don't show in the Users & Groups > Login Items control panel.